# write rendered output from mustache to new HTML file

Tags: php, codeigniter, mustache

I'm new to Mustache templating so please be kind.

My approach is to create a new HTML file based on a template HTML. I successfully integrated Mustache on my CodeIgniter application, via:

```
require 'system/libraries/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php';
// Create instance of autoloader
Mustache_Autoloader::register();
// Instantiate Mustache class
$m = new Mustache_Engine;
echo $m->render('Hello, {{planet}}!', array('planet' => 'Mars'));
```

Now I have a template HTML located on `application/templates/my_html_template.php`, this file contains HTML semantics having some variable template {{words}}. I do understand that I need to render this but I can't seem to understand how things work. Should I use `file_get_contents` then `fwrite` the rendered HTML from Mustache to create the desired output of a new HTML file to a certain directory?

Answer (score 2):

The `Mustache_Engine` constructor takes an array of options, one of them is the [`loader`](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/blob/master/src/Mustache/Engine.php#L53-L54).
This class will be responsible to get the template content from the first parameter that passed to `render`. The default loader is `Mustache_Loader_StringLoader` but there's other loaders in the library you can use like [Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/blob/master/src/Mustache/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php). This sould take care of the loading the template file part of the task. Once it rendered you can use `file_put_contents()` to shove it into a file.